# Break on Arbitrary Event in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, breakpoints, visual-studio-2003, visual-studio-debugging, code-editor

I'm trying to trace some legacy code at work, Visual Studio 2003 and .Net 1.1.  There are actions done on Keypress and Text change that I know happen but, the Text fields themselves are made dynamically or are a control.  I need to find the code that is executed when these things happen.  Because of some poor architecture decisions on this piece of software the code is very spaghetti and hard to manually figure out.

What I would like to do is set Visual Studio into a mode where it would break when a specific event is handled regardless of the handler.  This way I can get into the code and see through what is being done to make the translations and set variables.

Ultimately I'm trying to trace down when this code accesses the database to do lookups and updates so, allowing to watch for when a database connection happens would also be helpful and achieve much the same thing.

Comment: There is no such mode.  The number of places where you access the dbase in the code should be limited.  Set breakpoints on them.

Comment: Thats what I'm doing right now... There is 2,530 of them.